# Minimal sum of Betti numbers of Kähler manifold with trivial canonical bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, complex-geometry

Let $M$ be a closed Kähler manifold of real dimension $2n$. Suppose the canonical bundle of $M$ is holomorphically trivial.

Is it true that $\sum_{i=0}^{2n} b_i(M)=n+3\implies n=1$?

Comment: Perhaps this is obvious, but how do we know there is no rigid CY3 with Picard number one?

Comment: @PiotrAchinger based on https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.06303 no CY3 is known with $b_2+b_3=3$

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but it doesn't prove there does not exist one.

Comment: It follows from the Kodaira-Enriques classification that there are no counterexamples with $n = 2$.